# Listening for phone code not executing?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, listener

My app plays audio, and so I want to mute my app's audio when the user gets a call. That way the music won't be playing over the users call. I have used `phoneStateListener` , but for some reason the methods in it aren't executing-I know because the logs aren't displaying:

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Incoming call: Pause music
                  TwentySeconds.stopTimer(); //Stop service which mutes app
           Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, Main_Menu.class);
            startActivity(i);

                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "INCOMING CALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v(TAG, "INCOMING CALL");

            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //Not in call: Play music
                Log.v(TAG, "NOT IN A CALL");
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold
                   TwentySeconds.stopTimer(); //Stop service which mutes app
           Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, Main_Menu.class);
            startActivity(i);

                Log.v(TAG, "CALL IS ACTIVE!");
                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "DIALING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    };
```

I have looked all over the web to find out how to do this--One way is I found is to use the intent, but that requires extending BroadcastReceiver, and I can't extend two things. So, for now, the phoneStateListener is doing absolutely nothing. I really appreciate all of your help in fixing my `PhoneStateListener`.

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to quote the TelephonyManager?

```
TelephonyManager manager = this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Try this:

```
public class PhoneCallStateActivity extends Activity {
   TelephonyManager manager;

   @override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main); 

      manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      manager.listen(new MyPhoneStateListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
   }

    class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{

       @override
       public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
          switch(state) {
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
          //TODO:
          break;

          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
          //TODO：
          break;

          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
          //TODO:
          break;

          default:
          break;
         }

       }

       super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code,it is good. But i am just thinking about your manifest file, did you given enough permissions to read phone state. Have a look at my manifest file (which is working):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.truiton.phonestatelistener"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".PhoneStateListenerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
 
</manifest>
```

It is better to access / use this "Custom Phone State Listener" class with the TelephonyManager like as follows:

```html
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class PhoneStateListenerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 TelephonyManager tManager;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  tManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(this),
    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE
      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO // Requires API 17
      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION
      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY
      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE
      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE
      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS
      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR
      | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_MESSAGE_WAITING_INDICATOR);
 }

}
```

Here we are setting the tManager.listen method a new object for CustomPhoneStateListener and in the events parameter a bitwise-OR combination of Android [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) LISTEN_ flags is passed.

You can set your own custom phone state listener, (I am just adding mine here) :

```js
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
  
  public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
     mContext = context;
  }
  
  @Override
 public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
 super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
 switch (state) {
 case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
 Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCallStateChanged: CALL_STATE_IDLE");
 break;
 case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
 Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCallStateChanged: CALL_STATE_RINGING");
 break;
 case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
 Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCallStateChanged: CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
 break;
 default:
 Log.i(LOG_TAG, "UNKNOWN_STATE: " + state);
 break;
 }
 }
```